# R Using loop to create 4 separate graphs of matrices (using lines function)

Tags: r, loops, graph

I am currently doesn't some testing and analysis of the Micahelis-Menten enzyme kinetics model. And what my code is attempting to do is to change the rate parameter th1 to 50% up to 200% of it's max value.

What I want to do though is I want to produce 4 separate graphs which show what happens to MM1, MM2, MM3, MM4 when changing the rate parameter.

The issue that I have is regarding the "q" loop and where I use the "if", "else if" and "else" functions found near the end of my code.

```
MM <- list(Pre = matrix(c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0), ncol=4), Post = 
matrix(c(0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1),ncol=4), M= c("x1"=301,"x2"=120, "x3"=0, 
"x4"=0), h = function (x, t, th = c(1.66e-3, 1e-4 , 0.1)) 
{
  with(as.list(c(x, th)), {
    return(c(th[1] * x1 * x2, th[2] * x3, th[3] * x3))
  })
})

gillespied1 <- function (N, T = 100, dt = 1, ...) 
{
  tt = 0
  n = T%/%dt
  x = N$M
  S = t(N$Post - N$Pre)
  u = nrow(S)
  v = ncol(S)
  xmat = matrix(ncol = u, nrow = n)
  i = 1
  target = 0
  repeat {
    h = N$h(x, tt, ...)
    h0 = sum(h)
    if (h0 < 1e-10) 
      tt = 1e+99
    else if (h0>3000){
      tt=1e+99
      xmat[i] <- xmat[i-1] ###
      i = i + 1
      if(i > n)
        return(ts(xmat, start = 0, deltat = dt)) ###
    }
    else tt = tt + rexp(1, h0)
    while (tt >= target) {
      xmat[i, ] = x
      i = i + 1
      target = target + dt
      if (i > n) 
        return(ts(xmat, start = 0, deltat = dt))
    }
    j = sample(v, 1, prob = h)
    x = x + S[, j]
  }
}



 cl = rainbow(13)
    for(q in 1:4){
      plot(1, type="n", xlab="Time", ylab="Concentration of Substrate",xaxt='n', 

    xlim=c(0, 1200), ylim=c(0, 310), main="Micahaelis-Menten:Changing Substrate rate parameter")
      for(i in seq(from=50, to=200, by=25)){
        MM$h = function (x, t, th = c(1.66e-3*(i/100), 1e-4, 0.1)) 
        {
          with(as.list(c(x, th)), {
            return(c(th[1] * x1 * x2, th[2] * x3, th[3] * x3))
          })
        }
        out = gillespied1(MM,T=300,dt=0.1)
        MM1 <- out[,1]
        MM2 = out[,2]
        MM3 = out[,3]
        MM4 = out[,4]
        for (j in 1:40)  {
          out = gillespied1(MM, T=300, dt=0.1)
          MM1 = cbind(MM1,out[,1])
          MM2 = cbind(MM2,out[,2])
          MM3 = cbind(MM3,out[,3])
          MM4 = cbind(MM4,out[,4])
        }
        a =matrix(rowMeans(MM1))
        b = matrix(rowMeans(MM2))
        c = matrix(rowMeans(MM3))
        d = matrix(rowMeans(MM4))
        if (q = 1) {
          lines(a, lwd="1.5", col =cl[2*((i/25)-1)-1])
        } else if ( q=2) {
          lines(b, lwd="1.5", col =cl[2*((i/25)-1)-1])
        } else if ( q=3) {
          lines(c, lwd="1.5", col =cl[2*((i/25)-1)-1])
        } else
          lines(d, lwd="1.5", col =cl[2*((i/25)-1)-1])
      }
      axis(side = 1, at = (0:300)*10 , labels = 0:300)
      legend("topright", legend=c("50%","75%","100%","125%","150%","175%", "200%"), lty =c(rep(1)), lwd=c(rep(1)), title ="% of original substrate rate parameter", col=cl[seq(1,13,2)], cex=0.4)
    }
```

I keep getting this error

```
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

but I can't tell why.

If my code was working perfectly I should end up with 4 graphs, each graph containing 7 lines.

Any help would be amazing. Thanks.

Comment: if (q = 1) Equality test should use "==" i think , http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/library/base/html/Comparison.html

Comment: Oh my god lol, yeah that fixed it. Thank you

Comment: Posted the same as answer, glad to help!

Comment: it's always the obvious things I miss

Comment: Happens to everyone of us all the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [link](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/library/base/html/Comparison.html):

**Relational Operators**

*Description*

Binary operators which allow the comparison of values in atomic vectors.

**Usage**

```
x == y
```